# A Java Annotation on variable/field/parameter Type is lost in identifier references, why is this?

Tags: java, annotations

The following example illustrates the basic problem.

```
public class MyClass {
  private @Foo MyClass _myClass;

  public void test() {
    // the type information for the `_myClass` reference does not include the `@Foo` annotation 
    Object obj = _myClass;
  }
}
```

Using an annotation processor or compiler plugin you can examine the type of the `_myClass` initializer in the `Object obj = _myClass` variable declaration.

Specifically, the `JCTree.JCIdent#type` field corresponding with the `_myClass` reference does not have the `@Foo` annotation in the metadata.  This appears to be a general problem in the compiler -- all annotation metadata is lost during attribution of expressions etc.  It prevents an entire class of features that could otherwise work with annotation.

Or, perhaps I am missing something obvious?

I would rather have logged this as a feature request on the [JDK Bug tracker](http://bugs.openjdk.java.net), but that is a closed system :(

I'm hopeful someone from that project may be lurking here and can offer more information.

Comment: Annotations are not part of the type. They mark fields, classes, methods, parameters, but not types.

Comment: It is definitely part of the Type.  In Java 11 it is stored in `Type#metadata`, in Java 8 if a class is annotated it is an `AnnotatedType`.  Both types define the method `getAnnotationMirrors()`.